# How to use my python random forest classifier in web app that is coded in HTML, Javascript and nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, machine-learning

Hi I am developing a machine learning web application for which I need to use a random forest classifier, and I don't have any idea how to integrate the python code with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple !

1. create small web server with flask. Host you model on the machine where your server lies.
2. Create route for receiving HTTP requests.
3. Trigger the "execute_model()" function in the specific API
4. Send response after getting return value

Comment: can i use the server that i am using node on for this method or does it have to be two different servers?

Comment: i think two servers might be ok ! because you keep node.js server away from the CPU intensive tasks which are done flask server !